# Using React with Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I've been trying to use react with electron. I have set up react, I'm building the react site which outputs the site in the build/ dir. When I try to load the built index.html, the site does not want to work. This is because the built react site is not meant to be loaded locally, but is meant to be served.

My question is; how can I load my react site in electron? Both for production build and local development. I do not need any hacky duck tape solution to get hot reload, I simply want a robust solution to get react in electron. Is this where webpack or babel comes in?

Yes, I am aware that there are boilerplates available, but using those does not help when I don't understand what all the packages do and why they are there. And most of them seem heavily bloated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using webpack was the answer. Webpack combines everything in one js file so It's the perfect solution for electron.